# When should "doctor" be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization

In the following sentence, should the word "doctor" be treated as a common noun, or should it begin with a capital letter?

> The doctor will see you now.

Comment: In the general case, "doctor" is not a proper noun and should not generally be capitalized.  With Dr. Who, however, it's more of a proper noun and should be capitalized.  I can't quite put my finger on why, hence this is a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: It it's used as a title or a name, capitalize it; otherwise, don't.

Comment: One could argue that "doctor" becomes a proper noun in "Mrs. Smith, Doctor will see you now," but that usage is uncommon in the US (though I believe that it's common in the UK).  But when prefaced by "the" (and not part of a longer title), "doctor" is hardly ever a proper noun.

Comment: The usual terminology for a noun that does not get capitalized is "common noun."

Comment: Doctor? Doctor who?

Answer (score 2):

When you can add a surname to the sentence, it should be capitalised;

> Doctor Smith will see you now

When it is a job description, (usually prefixed with 'a' or 'the') leave it out;

> The doctor will see you now.

Think of 'Doctor' as becoming part of someone's actual name, and so when it's used to address a specific person, treat it like a proper noun.

Answer (score 1):

It should always be capitalized when abbreviated to Dr., as in Dr. Trump.

It must never be capitalized if it's spelled out and not followed by a surname or Christian name. As in

> "The doctor will see you now even though he doesn't really want to."

Comment: It's always capitalised when used as a prestigious title. 'The Doctor meets his old enemy, the Meddling Monk'. It's just rarely used as a prestigious title in everyday usage. However, [Jane Straus, at GrammarBook.com](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/capital.asp) conceded: 6a 'Capitalize a formal title when it is used as a direct address. The more formal the title, the more likely it is to be capitalized.

Examples:
Will you take my temperature, Doctor?
We're sorry to report, Captain, that we're headed for choppy waters.
That's what you say, mister.
Good afternoon, sweetheart.'